# The axis appears behind the drawing after converting form Asymptote to PDF

Tags: pdf, asymptote

I am trying to convert my figure from Asymptote to PDF. In Asymptote it looks fine. However, in PDF the axis appears behind the drawing.

I use the following command to produce PDF:

```
asy.exe -f pdf -render 0 fig.asy
```

MWE:

```
import graph3;
import three;
import contour3;
size3(250);
currentprojection=orthographic(-5,-9,3);
currentlight = light(-9, -9, 9);
triple v1 = (1, 0, 1);
triple v2 = (0, 1, 1);
triple v3 = (2, 2, 2);
draw(surface(v1--v2--v3--cycle),gray(0.9));
draw(v1--v2--v3--cycle,currentpen+1);
dot(v1);
dot(v2);
dot(v3);
xaxis3("$x$", 0, 2.7, OutTicks(), arrow=Arrow3);
yaxis3("$y$", 0, 2.7, OutTicks(NoZero), arrow=Arrow3);
zaxis3("$z$", 0, 2.7, OutTicks(NoZero), arrow=Arrow3);
```

How it looks in Asymptote (version 2.38): [image]
How it appears in PDF (Adobe Reader): [image]

Any idea or advice is really appreciated!

Comment: I do not know if that helps but something seemingly related is mentioned on p. 55 of [this great tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf). One reason why I cannot say more is that I cannot even reproduce the upper screen shot with your code. Nevertheless it *may* help if you add `settings.render=0;
settings.outformat="pdf";`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have looked at p.55 and I see that certain problems exist. Unfortunately, I cannot understand how to apply that approach to my problem. Adding  `settings.outformat="pdf"; settings.render=0;` take no effect, i.e. PDF with the same issue is produced. But if I click on PDF (enable PRC content), I see the correct image like in the upper figure.

Comment: Note: If desired you can get rid of the PRC content using `settings.prc = false;`. I don't think that's your primary goal, but it can make the output easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-render=0` it is not possible to have automatic visible/hidden faces managment. It is a 2D projection of the 3D scene. The only advantage is the vectorized output.
When you click on your pdf (with adobe) a 3D rendering engine is launched, the PRC engine of Adobe. If you print it or export the output it is a bitmap image and not vectorized. The main advantage is the 3D rendering with visible/hidden faces support. (in fact I do not understand why `-render=0 -f pdf` gives the superposition of the pdf figure and prc).
It is the same with `-render=n` with `n>0`, the OpenGL engine and the output is a bitmap image.
(see [Errors with Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212234/errors-with-asymptote/212283#212283))

With some efforts and for simple 3D pictures it is possible to manage by yourself the visible/hidden faces/lines. But you have to do by yourself (the painting algorithm, depending of the eye...).

In the very specific case it is possible to draw `zaxis` after by putting the option `above=true`. Try with

```
zaxis3("$z$", 0, 2.7, OutTicks(NoZero), arrow=Arrow3,above=true);
```